# How to display html form values in same page after submit?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

could give me an example to extract data from input after submit button and send in same page to output h2?

This my input and submit button.

```
<div class="input-field col s6">
  <i class="material-icons prefix">perm_identity</i>
  <input placeholder="..." id="nameClient" name="nameClient" type="text" class="validate">
  <label for="nameClient">Nome do cliente:</label>
</div>

<button class="btn waves-effect waves-light indigo" id="publish-sell" type="submit"><i class="material-icons left">attach_money</i>EFETUAR VENDA</button>
```

Was using this example to extract the typed data input to another input by means of a click.

```
$("#copyMapResearch").click(function () {
  var endereco = $("#addressDeliveryClient").val();
  $("#pac-input").val(endereco);
});

$("#copyToForm").click(function () {
  var endereco = $("#pac-input").val();
  $("#addressProvider").val(endereco);
});
```

The purpose of this code is to introduce it into a `complete function` of ajax.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#draft-sell').click(function () {
    var payload = {
      nameClient: $('#nameClient').val(),
      nameFantasySell: $('#nameFantasySell').val(),
      addresOfClientSell: $('#addresOfClientSell').val(),
      annotations: $('#annotations').val(),
      neighborhood: $('#neighborhood').val(),
      cep: $('#cep').val(),
      phoneLandline: $('#phoneLandline').val(),
      cellphone: $('#cellphone').val(),
      autocompleteBusinessReseller: $('#autocompleteBusinessReseller').val(),
      amountProduct: $('#amountProduct').val(),
      productSoldSell: $('#productSoldSell').val(),
      producFinalPrice: $('#producFinalPrice').val(),
      registeredDaySell: $('#registeredDaySell').val()
    };
    $.ajax({
      url: "/product/sell-draft",
      type: "POST",
      contentType: "application/json",
      processData: false,
      data: JSON.stringify(payload),
      complete: function (data) {
        // here is the place of the code that will extract the data from the data entered in the input and write in front-end
      }
    });
  });
});
```

This my final html tag to display results.

```
<h2 class="left-align white-text person-name" id="nameClientReciept">
```

Thanks for help!!

Comment: Once  you submit you open a new page !

Comment: @ivan.rosina I want the results to be displayed on the page itself through a script will write the information sent in a h2

Comment: I understand but in this case you first have to remove submit button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use a form with submit button, then you need to use the `submit` action of the form, and prevent the default.

```js
let form       = document.querySelector('form');
let nameClinet = document.querySelector('#nameClient');
let output     = document.querySelector('#output');

form.onsubmit = function(e){
  e.preventDefault(); // stop the submit from actually happening
  console.log("Client Name:", nameClient.value);  
  output.innerText = nameClient.value;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet"/>
<form>
  <div class="input-field col s6">
    <i class="material-icons prefix">perm_identity</i>
    <input placeholder="..." id="nameClient" name="nameClient" type="text" class="validate">
    <label for="nameClient">Nome do cliente:</label>
    <h2 id="output"></h2>
  </div>

  <button 
    class="btn waves-effect waves-light indigo" 
    id="publish-sell" 
    type="submit">
      <i class="material-icons left">attach_money</i>EFETUAR VENDA
    </button>
</form>
```